# Using HTTP Pipelining with Jetty HTTPClient

Tags: java, http, jetty, jetty-httpclient

I'm trying to figure out how to use HTTPClient (org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient) so it will pipeline HTTP Requests.

I've tried to create some ContentExchange instances and applying the send() method for each, in an asynchronous mode, but each HTTP request has waited for it response before the next request was sent.

Can you please supply a code snippet for this case?

Comment: looking at the docs for the HttpExchange class, this seems like a server-side class, as it returns the response, yet your description indicates that you are using it client side? Can you confirm where you are using HttpExchange, and perhaps post a code snippet of your client side code?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ContentExchange. and yes I'm using it for client side.

Comment: Here is another thread on this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777005/java-based-http-client-which-supports-pipelining

Answer (score 0):

I think the apache http client may help

[Java based HTTP Client which supports Pipelining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777005/java-based-http-client-which-supports-pipelining)

Also, there was another one in that thread as well that might work.  I guess you can try some of the clients from that thread.