# Java based HTTP Client which supports Pipelining

Tags: java, http, sockets

Do you know of any free Java library which support the HTTP pipelining option of HTTP/1.1  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPClient apparently supports pipelining here:

http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/

but I haven't tried it personally and can't verify this.

Comment: Commons HTTPClient has an open RFE for the same functionality - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-258

Comment: That seems terribly old: the web page is dated 2001. Is it still alive?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find any common ones supporting pipe-lining. Jetty HttpClient seems to support it from document but I couldn't make it to do it.

Please note that Pipeline is different from keep-alive. Keep-alive just means reuse the connection but it may still send only one request at a time over the connection. With pipe-lining, you can send several requests at the same time over the same connection and wait for their respective responses.

Answer (score 0):

[hotpotato](http://hotpotato.factor45.org/) will support pipelining **really** soon. Performance-wise, it's way superior to Apache's HTTP Client, especially in high concurrency environments (multiple threads using the same instance of the client).

I still need to publish the results but on a LAN test, I'm getting ~7000req/s (hotpotato) vs ~100req/s (apache's). Of course, a great deal of the merit must go to Netty, the amazing framework hotpotato is built upon ;)

If you don't need a fancy full-fledged client, take a look [here](http://bruno.factor45.org/blag/2010/08/23/pipelining-support-in-hotpotato/) for a simpler version.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my answer is about a year old, but as this is one of the top links for "java http pipelining", I thought it was relevant.

Hotpotato does indeed now support pipelining, and in my limited experience it's been working great so far. Also has a nice API to boot.

http://hotpotato.biasedbit.com/

EDIT: Looks like this project is now unmaintained and the author recommends the Async HTTP client: https://github.com/ning/async-http-client/

Answer (score 0):

[Apache HttpComponents Core 5](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/index.html) supports HTTP/1.1 pipelining. The example could be found [here](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/5.0.x/httpcore5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http/examples/AsyncPipelinedRequestExecutionExample.java).