# Using Java NIO for pipelined Http

Tags: java, nio, apache-httpcomponents, pipelining

Researching the web, I've found that pipelined HTTP is much faster and more power efficient (specially for mobile devices) than queued or parallel connections. The support from general libraries however seams to be small.  Just recently has the widespread Apache HttpCore project gained support through its NIO module.

At least it says so on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining#Other_implementations) and a few places in the documentation. My problem is, that I have been unable to find any examples or tutorials on how to use this for sending simple piped requests. Neither the HttpCore NIO docs, nor Google codesearch has given me anything looking like Http pipelining.

Can you give me a simple example on how to use this module for sending two gets in a pipe and responding two their answer?

Comment: maybe this question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298257/http-1-1-pipelining

Comment: @Raoul_Duke Kinda, but they discuss how to write a pipelining http client. My problem is that HttpCore now seams to support it out of the box, but doesn't tell how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wait till Android gets a proper implementation built in. If Google hasn't bothered using it, it might just not be worth all the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a serious look at this right now:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/HttpgetwithCharBufferandByteBuffer.htm