# Android HTTP pipelining

Tags: android, http

Does somebody know a library with the HTTP client pipelining support?

Comment: Do you need an HTTP Server or an HTTP Client?

Comment: @Josef, I need a client. @Samuh what does "work on ur accetp rate" means? Thanks both of u for the answers

Comment: Ok, and what exactly do you mean by *pipelining support*? Does the built-in Apache HttpClient not support it?

Comment: @Josef, Yes it does not support. If I have no misunderstood, with the pipelining supports is possible to make multiple requests to the server without waiting the answer. Normally I made a request and waiting for an answer..

Comment: HTTP pipelining is a (required!) feature of HTTP 1.1 which allows the client to fire multiple requests in the same TCP stream before receiving any response. It's actually pretty nice for high latency connections, but seems to be disabled in all major HTTP clients (except Opera, maybe): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java based HTTP Client which supports Pipelining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777005/java-based-http-client-which-supports-pipelining)

Answer (score -1):

You could try the one from the response of [Java based HTTP Client which supports Pipelining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777005/java-based-http-client-which-supports-pipelining).

[HTTP 1.1 Pipelining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298257/http-1-1-pipelining) has some additional information.

Comment: thanks, I had already read the response of the link you posted. no useful answer in it.

Comment: http://hotpotato.biasedbit.com/ mentions supporting pipelining in the very first sentence, in bold. Doesn't that library work on Android?

Comment: I tried hotpotato but the result was unsatisfactory